# Using %d with char , unexpected results

Tags: c, printf, scanf, mingw, format-specifiers

Text editor : VS code

Compiler : minGW

I was needed to store a number between 1-10, so I thought why don't store it in a **char** variable because it takes only 1 byte.

so, look at the following code

```
char a = 3;
printf("%d", a);
```

OUTPUT

```
3
```

it worked fine

Then I decided to take value as input using **scanf**

Here's the code for that

```
char a;
printf("Enter number : ");
scanf("%d", &a);
printf("You entered : %d", a);
```

OUTPUT

```
Enter number : 9
You entered : 9
```

It worked fine too, but problem lies when I tried with two variables

Look at the the code below

```
char a = 2, b = 3;

printf("before scanf a : %d\n", a);
printf("before scanf b : %d\n", b);

printf("Enter new value of a : ");
scanf("%d", &a);

printf("after scanf a : %d\n", a);
printf("after scanf b : %d\n", b);
```

OUTPUT

```
before scanf a : 2
before scanf b : 3     
Enter new value of a : 9
after scanf a : 9
after scanf b : 0 //Notice value of b has changed to 0
```

Even though, I didn't even touched b's value. still it changed.
.
I tried a lot to figure it out but failed, I'm a beginner.
I think it's something to do with stdin/out stream.
please help me here..

Comment: `scanf("%d", &a);` is undefined behavior so anything can happen. [What is undefined behavior and how does it work?](https://software.codidact.com/q/277486)

Comment: `scanf` is not `printf`...

Comment: The `char` passed to `printf` is promoted to `int` but a pointer is not promoted to a different type.

Comment: try printing the address of `a` and `b` also in first `printf` statements, mostly they are getting allocated successive addresses, and your `b` values goes for a toss, since they are of 1 byte type but you are trying to extract and store 4 byte values

Comment: @user3121023: The range of a `char` is implementation-defined. For a signed `char`, it must be at least −127 to +127, but it may be more.

Comment: Memory overflow, "%d" in scanf requires a variable of size of an int, and you used a smaller, a char, then the value that would be stored in the variable overflowed to the stack

Answer (score 1):

The format specifier `%d` specifies int, not char. When you use this format specifier with `printf` and pass a char, this doesn't really matter because char gets implicitly promoted to an int.

But with scanf, you end up passing a char pointer (note that `scanf` uses `&a` instead of simply `a`) where `scanf` expects an int pointer. Hence `scanf` ends up copying an int into a char, which means that data spills over into the adjacent memory location(s). In your case, this adjacent location happens to be the variable `b`, thus the value of `b` gets overwritten with the MSB of the integer that is input, which in this case is 0.

PS: I should also mention the fact that you shouldn't really rely on this behaviour. What I mentioned above is the most likely explanation for your observation. This particular scenario falls under undefined behaviour so a different compiler, different hardware or a different run of the same program could theoretically have resulted in a drastically different outcome and it would still be perfectly legal! The proper solution is to use an int instead of a character. On a modern machine, you are not saving much anyway with these antics.

Comment: Probably should make mention of undefined behavior in there somewhere, maybe around adjacent memory locations.

Comment: @rykker Thanks, fixed!

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for your efforts, can you please tell me that what is the alternative way of storing number in least memory storage.

Comment: *this doesn't really matter because char gets implicitly promoted to an int*  There are probably some cases on systems where `char` is unsigned where it does matter.

Comment: what does it mean that **"char gets promoted to int"**

Comment: @anonymous you could use the right format specifier (`%hhd`) or use `int a` instead of `char`. On promotion rules, please take a look at this page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46073295/implicit-type-promotion-rules

Comment: @AndrewHenle Perhaps, but only if you try storing negative numbers in an unsigned char.

Answer (score 1):

`scanf("%d", &a);` instructs `scanf` to read a decimal numeral and assign it to an `int` pointed to by `&a`. Since `&a` points to a `char`, not an `int`, the behavior is not defined by the C standard.

Proper code is to declare `a` as a `signed char` and use `scanf("%hhd", &a);`. (Technically, there is no conversion specifier to assign to a `char`.)

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is that your program thinks **a** is of type **int**. Since the size of an **int** is 4 bytes, if you do:

```c
char a = 2, b = 3, c = 4, d = 5, e = 6;
```

`scanf("%d", &a)` will corrupt the values of **b**, **c**, **d** (but will not corrupt the value of **e**, because **e** is the 5th byte, and the size of **int** is **4**), because *scanf* thinks that you've passed a pointer to an **int**, not to a **char**.

Comment: A compiler will not necessarily allocate `b`, `c`, and `d` adjacent to `a`, nor will it necessarily allocate `e` away from `a`. Further, if `b`, `c`, and `d` are adjacent to `a`, they are not necessarily on the side that bytes beyond `a` would spill to. And the compiler may optimize them away completely if they are unused or store them in a register if it has sufficient register space available.

Comment: Keep it simple. There's absolute no reason to involve structs and padding, just read the character correctly. Or read an int if you want an int.

Comment: It is still UB. with `struct`.